# How to make a filebeat config to collect a specific lines from a file

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

have a file log aud of oracle and i need to collect the whole block instead of whole file. the block is from ACTION field to ACTION NUMBER

> log file as below

```
Thu Nov  9 10:20:24 2023 +01:00
LENGTH : '373'
ACTION :[122] 'select 'export nls_nchar_characterset="'||value||'"' from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET''
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[0] ''
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '3256053857'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[12] 's01vl9926909'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[1] '3'

Thu Nov  9 10:20:24 2023 +01:00
LENGTH : '1575'
ACTION :[1323] 'select 'export db_patchset_new="'||max_ver||'"' from (
select length(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', '')) max_length,
       max(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', '')) max_ver
from   (select description from ( select da.description, da.action_time apply, nvl(dr.action_time, da.action_time-1) rollback
                                  from (select description, max(action_time) action_time from dba_registry_sqlpatch where action='APPLY'    group by description) da,
                                       (select description, max(action_time) action_time from dba_registry_sqlpatch where action='ROLLBACK' group by description) dr
                                  where da.description=dr.description(+)
                                )
        where apply > rollback
       )
where  (upper(description) like '%DATABASE%PATCH%' or upper(description) like '%DATABASE%RELEASE%') and upper(description) not like '%JAVA%' and upper(description) not like '%JVM%'
group by length(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', ''))
order by 1 desc
)
where rownum=1'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[0] ''
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '3256053857'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[12] 's01vl9926909'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[1] '3'
```

I used the include_lines pattern to collect these specific lines but my probleme here is that in the field "ACTION" sometimes there is actions that contains long queries and my conf collect only the first line instead of the whole query.

> example here my event doesnt collect the whole query it stops at word **FROM**

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-11-09T13:34:21.491Z","@metadata":{"beat":"filebeat","type":"_doc","version":"7.17.0"},"message":"ACTION:'select 'export db_patchset_new="'||max_ver||'"' from ('","fields":{"env":"staging"},"host":{"name":"s01vl9926909"},"event":{"timezone":"+01:00"},"log":{"offset":811,"file":{"path":"/apps/oracle/diag/rdbms/q08775kp1/Q08775KP10/audit/Q08775KP10_ora_29807_20231109143420100545459814.aud"}},"input":{"type":"log"},"ecs":{"version":"1.12.0"}
```

at the fisrt time my file input_Oracle.yml was like below; it work fine but the problem was ACTION field

> my inputs files config at frst time work fine

```
  enabled: true
  tags: ["linux-Oracle"]
  #ignore_older: 4h
  close_inactive: 30s

  paths:
   /apps/oracle/diag/rdbms/*/*/audit/*.aud

  include_lines: ['^LENGTH :', '^ACTION :', '^DATABASE USER:', '^PRIVILEGE :', '^CLIENT USER:', '^CLIENT TERMINAL:', '^STATUS:', '^DBID:', '^SESSIONID:', '^USERHOST:', '^CLIENT ADDRESS:', '^ACTION NUMBER:']
```

> then i try "Multiline messages" but it not works for me

```
type: log
  enabled: true
  tags: ["linux-Oracle"]
  #ignore_older: 4h
  close_inactive: 30s

  paths:
    - /apps/oracle/diag/rdbms/*/*/audit/*.aud

  multiline:
    pattern: '^ACTION :'
    negate: true
    match: after

  include_lines: ['^LENGTH :', '^DATABASE USER:', '^PRIVILEGE :', '^CLIENT USER:', '^CLIENT TERMINAL:', '^STATUS:', '^DBID:', '^SESSIONID:', '^USERHOST:', '^CLIENT ADDRESS:', '^ACTION NUMBER:']`
```

Is there a way to do that by combine line !!

Comment: Hey there, could you please provide a sample fo the log file to better understand what you want to achieve. As well as you current configuration ?

Comment: Can you also show what you would like to achieve and the current results you have ? You post is strating to look very complete

Comment: i have update my question and i put a block of the log file

Comment: {"@timestamp":"2023-11-09T13:34:21.491Z","@metadata":{"beat":"filebeat","type":"_doc","version":"7.17.0"},"message":"ACTION:'select 'export db_patchset_new="'||max_ver||'"' from ('","fields":{"env":"staging"},"host":{"name":"s01vl9926909"},"event":{"timezone":"+01:00"},"log":{"offset":811,"file":{"path":"/apps/oracle/diag/rdbms/q08775kp1/Q08775KP10/audit/Q08775KP10_ora_29807_20231109143420100545459814.aud"}},"input":{"type":"log"},"ecs":{"version":"1.12.0"},"agent":

i cant collect the whole query as one event at action field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution for my issue was like below

```
 - type: log
   enabled: true
   tags: ["oracle_audit"]
   ignore_older: 4h
   close_inactive: 30s
   multiline.type: pattern
   multiline.pattern: '^........\d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4}\s.\d\d:\d\d'
   multiline.negate: true
   multiline.match: after
   multiline.flush_pattern: '\r'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

You are right indeed to be using the multiline parser.
But I think you have made a slight misconfiguration.

## To Solve:

I believe this could help you.

I am matching on line starting with an Uppercase word.

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: srt
  paths:
    - /usr/share/filebeat/data.log
  include_lines: ['^LENGTH :', '^ACTION :', '^DATABASE USER:', '^PRIVILEGE :', '^CLIENT USER:', '^CLIENT TERMINAL:', '^STATUS:', '^DBID:', '^SESSIONID:', '^USERHOST:', '^CLIENT ADDRESS:', '^ACTION NUMBER:']
  parsers:
  - multiline:
      type: pattern
      pattern: '^[A-Z]+'
      negate: true
      match: after

output.console:
  pretty: true
```

Which is giving me the following objects:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "LENGTH : '373'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "ACTION :[122] 'select 'export nls_nchar_characterset=\"'||value||'\"' from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET''"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "DATABASE USER:[1] '/'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT TERMINAL:[0] ''"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "STATUS:[1] '0'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "DBID:[10] '3256053857'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "USERHOST:[12] 's01vl9926909'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "ACTION NUMBER:[1] '3'\n"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "LENGTH : '1575'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "ACTION :[1323] 'select 'export db_patchset_new=\"'||max_ver||'\"' from (\nselect length(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', '')) max_length,\n       max(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', '')) max_ver\nfrom   (select description from ( select da.description, da.action_time apply, nvl(dr.action_time, da.action_time-1) rollback\n                                  from (select description, max(action_time) action_time from dba_registry_sqlpatch where action='APPLY'    group by description) da,\n                                       (select description, max(action_time) action_time from dba_registry_sqlpatch where action='ROLLBACK' group by description) dr\n                                  where da.description=dr.description(+)\n                                )\n        where apply > rollback\n       )\nwhere  (upper(description) like '%DATABASE%PATCH%' or upper(description) like '%DATABASE%RELEASE%') and upper(description) not like '%JAVA%' and upper(description) not like '%JVM%'\ngroup by length(regexp_replace(substr(description,0,decode(instr(description,'('),0,length(description),instr(description,'('))),'[^0.0-9]', ''))\norder by 1 desc\n)\nwhere rownum=1'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "DATABASE USER:[1] '/'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT TERMINAL:[0] ''"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.184Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "STATUS:[1] '0'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.185Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "DBID:[10] '3256053857'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.185Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.185Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "USERHOST:[12] 's01vl9926909'"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-11-09T14:19:08.185Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.6.2"
  },
  "message": "CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''"
}
```

Comment: it didnt work for with long query it always stops at the end of line.
thank u so much for trying helping me to solve my problem

Comment: which version do you use ?

Comment: I use the `filestream` input also

Comment: im using log input not filestream 

=================================
filebeat version 7.17.0 (amd64), libbeat 7.17.0 [93708bd74e909e57ed5d9bea3cf2065f4cc43af3 built 2022-01-28 09:53:30 +0000 UTC]

Comment: Do you have a strong requirement for using `log` ? it is deprecated

Comment: yes 
had u tried with a long query that containt more than 2 lines ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I was able to parse your file (provided in your post) and obtain the result you wanted. So I believe my solution works. I don't understand why it is not working on your side. Have you tried my configuration ? What is failing ?

Comment: yes you config it works fine but for example if u had test it by using the block below it wont parse the whole query.

Comment: Which "Block Below" ? From the given data I made it work.